# How do i assign left and right movement to my 2d game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development, 2d-games

So I'm new to Csharp, and I am working on this script for a game. It's a 2D game. Ive already assigned jump movement to the game, however, I'm stuck on fixing the movement along the x axis.
I'd really appreciate your help.

```
    using UnityEngine;
    // this code uses physics to make player jump

    public class Movement2d : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private bool jumpKeyWasPressed;
        private bool movementRight;
        private CharacterController characterController;
        private Rigidbody2D rigidbodyComponent;
        private Vector3 moveSpeed;

        // Start is called before the first frame update
        void Start()
        {
            rigidbodyComponent = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
            characterController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
        }

        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update()
        {
            //Check if space key is pressed down
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
            {
                jumpKeyWasPressed = true;
            }
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow))
            {
                movementRight = true;
            }
        }

        private void FixedUpdate()
        {
            if (jumpKeyWasPressed)
            {
                //jump action assigned to space key
                rigidbodyComponent.AddForce(new Vector2(0, 10), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
                jumpKeyWasPressed = false;
            }
            if (movementRight)
            { 
                //moving right assigned to right arrow
                Rigidbody.MovePosition();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `RigidBody.MovePosition`, you'll want to move the player according to your speed and the time elapsed since the last frame (to account for frame stutters).

Assuming your horizontal speed is stored in the x-coordinate of your speed vector, you'll want to write:

`rigidBodyComponent.MovePosition(new Vector2(moveSpeed.x * Time.deltaTime, 0));`

To perform left movement, use the same code, but use `-moveSpeed.x` instead. In both cases, don't forget to set the movement bool to false afterwards.

Keep in mind, however, that using `RigidBody.MovePosition` could cause your character to go through walls at high speeds. Consider using `RigidBody.AddForce()` as you did for jumping if you want to avoid that.

Sources:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.MovePosition.html
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.AddForce.html

Comment: I've tried your suggestion and it gives me an error for RigidBody.MovePosition
Error CS0120 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property. Is it possible to use another command instead of .MovePosition?

Comment: Or is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Your script has a RigidBody named `rigidBodyComponent`, so use that to invoke the method with its arguments.